# WSUS shows computers as no status after a day...?

Tags: wsus

This is something driving me quite mad for quite some time, but I have not been able to get my fingers on it.

I have a WSUS that is working perfectly. WHen I get new patches computers are shown as missing them. I install them, they update that they have them.

THen, after a day they turn into "no status", although the status report shows a perfectly valid timestamp. The update log shows no obvious error.

Funny thing though ist hat they DO report status, because come next patchday, they are shown missing patches, and then after installing them they are shown as fully patched again after some time. And a day later or two - "no status".

Anyone an idea how to debug it? Known problem? I find a lot with "No status". The WSUS server is a fully patched 2012 r2, clients are Win8 / win 8.1 / various servers, the problems appears on all. It is not critical as missing patches are properly shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not an error or some issue with client or WSUS, with simple tweak you can fix it.
The machine reporting "No Status" on an UPDATE, is a normal indication between the time an update is first synchronized to the WSUS Server, and that machine executes its next detection.

All you need to do to make sure WSUS and windows machine are both in same time zone and should be match in time. On completion of time synchronization please click on check update once more time in machine  and refresh status page on server. The Machine will report to WSUS within 5 minute.

If not please reboot and run update check on machine again.